# Python/SQL how to append last line from a dataframe (or a dictionary) into SQL table

Tags: python, sql

I created some code where I loop through and track my progress with a counter.

But when I try to append the current line I am in, into my sql table it fails, this feels like it should be the easiest part of this work but keeps failing.

Below is how I connect to the db and try to append the new line (dictionary) in:

```
quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myserver;DATABASE=mydb;Integrated Security=true;")
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))

new_line.to_sql('newtable', schema='schema', if_exists= "append" , con=engine, index=False)
```

This fails even though the line contains the same headers.

What did work is when I appended a dataframe by mistake, but that was wrong since I just wanted to add the last line.

```
df_output = df_output.append(new_line, ignore_index=True)
df_output.to_sql('newtable', schema='schema', if_exists= "append", con=engine, index=False)
```

So, since it accepted the dataframe I tried to take the last line of the dataframe which is appended from the `new_line`:

```
df_output.iloc[-1].to_sql('newtable', schema='schema', if_exists= "append", con=engine, index=False)
```

I have tried creating dataframes made out of the line alone but none of these have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really unclassy solution I found, but I created the dataframe right before adding the line, so I will only have one line. Then append it to the SQL table and it worked.